# How can I hide/change jsp extension on browser address bar?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, nginx

I use nginx and tomcat for serving my site that written in jsp. How can I hide/change jsp extension on browser address bar?

Answer (score 3):

You can map each JSP in your web app's web.xml file.

```
<servlet>   
               <servlet-name>myTest</servlet-name>
               <jsp-file>/testing.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>myTest</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Using this example mapping, you just append "/test" to your web app's url.

Answer (score 2):

Say you want "myExt" to be used now. You will have to Write a Filter/Servlet which maps to *.myExt. This servlet would intercept all the Requests coming for ".myExt" and internally forward it to ".jsp"

Following goes inside web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyExt Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.MyExtServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyExt Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.myExt</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Following goes inside Servlet

```
public class MyExtServlet extends HttpServlet {

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp) {
      // put your custom code here. I am just to replace the ext
      String url = req.getServletPath();
      Rsp.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(req,rsp);
   }
}
```

I just wrote the code on the fly. Hence my apologies for any compilation issues with it, but it should give you an idea of what could be done.

Answer (score -2):

Since it's not been said yet in other answers, I'll say it: you should not have URLs pointing to JSPs in the first place. Use an MVC framework like Stripes or Spring MVC, which

- allows for Java actions to handle the presentation logic (validation, error handling, etc.), delegates to a business layer for the actual business logic, and prepares the data to be shown
- dispatches to a JSP to generate the HTML markup

Having Java code in JSPs is unsafe, unmaintainable, and promotes copy'n paste programming rather than clean design.